# Pagination issue when search result

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 2 Model `Playlist` and `PlaylistTrack` PlalistTrack model contains track of playlist. One playlist has many tracks.

Table: Playlist(`id`,`name`)

Table: PlaylistTrack(`id`,`track_id`,`playlist_id`)

Following my code.

```
$conditions=array();
if(isset($this->params->query['search']) && $this->params->query['search']!="")
{
  $conditions['AND']['Playlist.name   LIKE']="%".$this->params->query['search']."%";
}
$this->paginate = array(
                'fields'=>array('Playlist.*','count(`PlaylistTrack`.`track_id`) as tracks'),
                'group' => "Playlist.id",
                'limit' => 10,
                'conditions'=>$condtions,
                'joins'=>array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'playlist_tracks',
                        'alias' => 'PlaylistTrack',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'Playlist.id=PlaylistTrack.playlist_id'
                        )
                    )
                )
        );
$data = $this->paginate('Playlist');
```

For all record pagination will work fine but when I search from playlist by playlist_name then Display one record with search parameter but there **There are two page for one record**.

If any further code required just tell me I explain in detail.

Comment: Where is your seach condition.Please put all search conditons.

Comment: I put search condition and updated my question.

Comment: I think no need ['AND'] In the conditions array.Please try after removing ['AND'];

Comment: There are so many conditions that's why I include `AND` conditions and I also mentioned that working fine with all record only problem with search condtion

Comment: Put all the code written on this action

Comment: I am sure there is no issue of `AND` condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56314/discussion-between-chetanspeed511987-and-sadikhasan).